# Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 Connect to ethernet

Tags: networking, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

Is it possible, using some type of adapter or combination of adapters, to connect a Galaxy Tab 2 to a ethernet port.

Is it necessary to add some kind of kernel module? Which one? How do I do that?